# Google Cloud Datastore queries too slow when fetching all records

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am experiencing extremely slow performance of Google Cloud Datastore queries.

My entity structure is very simple:

```
calendarId, levelId, levelName, levelValue
```

And there are only about 1400 records and yet the query takes 500ms-1.2 sec to give back the data. Another query on a different entity also takes 300-400 ms just for 313 records.

I am wondering what might be causing such delay. Can anyone please give some pointers regarding how to debug this issue or what factors to inspect?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you set the chunk size on your query?

Comment: Can you share some code showing how you go about fetching the data? We might be able to help you optimize those queries.

Comment: where is the code ?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin That is a good point. We are using an API (on top of datastore APIs) which doesn't use prepared queries. This is something we can probably check, using prepared queries with chunk/pre-fetch size specified. However only concern I have is that it is a single query executed only once so probably these options too won't affect much. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Default chunk size is 10, you can go up to 500. That's a big difference in a number of fetches.

Comment: What the name of the API you're using? Is it a client library offered by google or a custom API built on top of the Datastore REST APIs?

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing expected behavior.  You shouldn't need to get that many entities when presenting a page to user.  Gmail doesn't show you 1000 emails, it shows you 25-100 based on your settings.  You should fetch a smaller number (e.g., the first 100) and implement some kind of paging to allow users to see other entities.

If this is backend processing, then you will simply need that much time to process entities, and you'll need to take that into account.

Note that you generally want to fetch your entities in large batches, and not one by one, but I assume you are already doing that based on the numbers in your question.

Comment: You are right, these tables don't have too much data so I am getting all the data and cache is created to serve UI. But this is not such a huge amount of data that it takes more than a second to retrieve. Is this really normal behavior?

Comment: "You shouldn't need to get that many entities when presenting a page to user" You do if you want to populate a user-facing table with real-time filtering. Otherwise everything is sluggish when you want to filter the rows of the table as you send the filter query to the backend, etc. SQLite can give me 10k rows in a few milliseconds, why does datastore take 1.5 seconds for 1500?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but you could try packing more data into a single entity by using embedded entities. Embedded entities are not true entities, they are just properties that allow for nested data. So instead of having 4 properties per entity, create an array property on the entity that stores a list of embedded entities each with those 4 properties. The max size an entity can have is 1MB, so you'll want to pack the array to get as close to that 1MB limit as possible.

This will lower the number of true entities and I suspect this will also reduce overall fetch time.

Comment: Actually data is very linear kinds, can't really have embedded entities in this case. However I will check on one point: Does having same number of records but fewer columns reduce fetch time.

Comment: Not sure. I'd like to think it would since the data per entity would be smaller.